# Symfony2 and Microsoft SQL Server on Mac and MAMP

Tags: sql-server, macos, symfony, mamp

I´m going to develop a Symfony2 application in my Mac OSX with MAMP, but the database (a Microsoft SQL Server one) is in another computer.

I setup everything (I followed this instruction http://jesusomar.com/2011/07/22/mamp-php-and-mssql )and if I check phpinfo() I see that mssql is active, but I´m getting this error:

> [PDOException]
>     could not find driver

any help or clue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have FreeTDS installed?

Comment: Yes I did install it. But I how can I be sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to check if FreeTDS is installed. You can run `tsql -C` to get information about MSSQL libraries in your computer. You should get something like this:

```
Version: freetds v0.91
freetds.conf directory: /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.91/etc
MS db-lib source compatibility: no
Sybase binary compatibility: no
Thread safety: yes
iconv library: yes
TDS version: 7.1
iODBC: no
unixodbc: no
SSPI "trusted" logins: no
Kerberos: no
```

If FreeTDS is not installed, you can do it with Homebrew (for example): `brew install freetds`.

Now you can use [MssqlBundle](https://github.com/intellectsoft-uk/MssqlBundle) to connect with your database.